# How to determine reason for unprocessed files in Drupal to Drupal migration

Tags: migrations

Finally ran my first file migration from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 using UI.

- 3100 Items
- 3036 Processed
- 62 Unprocessed
- 2498 messages

I am simply trying to figure out what those 62 files are, and why they did not process.

I looked at the "messages" link for the file migration task. They all say something like:

`2701   Informational   Deleted documents from index with query id:"pyli4t/file/3782" OR sm_parent_document_id:"pyl4t/file/3782"` Don't know what to do with this, or how to query for unprocessed files.

I looked at the **migrate_map_43b7eadb1file** table for the migration task, but don't see anything that indicates what files were not processed.

I looked at the **migrate_message_43b7eadb1file** table and was able to locate the two files that failed using this SQL statement: `SELECT * FROM migrate_message_43b7eadb1file WHERE level != 4` But, nothing about unprocessed files.

That's all I can think to do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this poster received an answer from the [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) module maintainer over at drupal.org, so for convenience I will post it here:

Source:[Issue#2476077: How to determine reason for unprocessed files](https://www.drupal.org/node/2476077#comment-9862819)

> Side issue first - that informational message is coming from some
>   contrib module (something search-related, perhaps) and not related to
>   migration per-se. Grep your codebase for "Deleted documents from
>   index" to see what it might be.
>
> So, the unprocessed count is precisely the count of source records,
>   minus the number of records in the map table (so, you will never find
>   an "unprocessed" record in the map table. All processed records are
>   recorded in the map table with an appropriate status.
>
> The first question is, are there really unprocessed records, or is the
>   source count off? The most common cause of "unprocessed" records being
>   reported is a malformed source query that has more than one row with
>   the same primary key (fid in this case) - this can happen when joining
>   to another table that has multiple rows per "base" row. Elsewhere
>   you've been speaking about extending migrate_d2d classes and modifying
>   their queries - could you have done that for the file query, and
>   joined to another table?
>
> The next step is to try to identify specific unprocessed files. If
>   your D6 and D7 databases are on the same MySQL server and accessible
>   with the same MySQL user, you can do something like:
>
> ```
> select d6.fid 
> from d6.files f
> left join d7.migrate_map_myfilemigration map on f.fid=map.sourceid1
> where map.sourceid1 is null
> ```
>
> If the dbs are not on the same server, you could try dumping the D6
>   files table (or just the fids) and loading it into a temp table on the
>   D7 server.

Answer (score 0):

In our case the reason for the unprocessed items was that we were returning FALSE in our source plugin's `prepareRow` method, after calling `parent::prepareRow`.

The [base method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21source%21SourcePluginBase.php/function/SourcePluginBase%3A%3AprepareRow/10) includes the following code to explicitly mark the row as ignored:

```
$this->idMap->saveIdMapping($row, [], MigrateIdMapInterface::STATUS_IGNORED);
```